# How to sort numerically by what's between square brackets

Tags: python, sorting, brackets

I have the following scenario, where a text file has something like the following output:

```
DecodingIndex[ 1]   PresentationIndex[ 2]
DecodingIndex[ 2]   PresentationIndex[ 3]
DecodingIndex[ 3]   PresentationIndex[ 1]
etc...
```

Since it shows the numbers within DecodingIndex sequential, I want it to be sorted instead by PresentationIndex. Like the following:

```
DecodingIndex[ 3]   PresentationIndex[ 1]
DecodingIndex[ 1]   PresentationIndex[ 2]
DecodingIndex[ 2]   PresentationIndex[ 3]
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Python? These numbers go all the way to to tens of thousands. The distance between the square brackets always has a gap for numbers less than 10, and then hugs the numbers e.g DecodingIndex[32100]

Hope that made sense and thanks for your help!

=======

Here's what I have tried:
1)I iterate through each line in the file and store into a lines[] list
2)Iterate through each item in the lines[] list, while using the following regex pattern `re.compile(r'PresentationIndex\[(.*?)\]')`
3)I then get the matches out of the result using group() and store these values in a new list
4)I then sort the list numerically by first turning the items into an int, then sorting, then turning it back into an string like this
5)Now I iterate through that list and insert the words PresentationIndex and square brackets in
6)Using the now sorted list of PresentationIndex, I iterate through each of these. For each iteration, I iterate through the whole output text file to search for the associated line and append this to a final list. This way I get my output in the order I want.

I started out with a file of about 32,000 lines. Doing this sort took about 3 hours...

Comment: There's an easy way. What have *you* tried?

Comment: I have abstracted the problem quite a bit. Not sure how I can paste all my code..? But I used regex to match everything inbetween the PresentationIndex brackets, then sorted them into a list numerically. Then using that, iterate through the orignal output file for the corresponding line... in a nutshell

Comment: And what's the problem then?

Comment: Don't paste *all* the code, paste the least amount of *relevant* code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It takes my script 3 hours to execute. It seems too inefficient and I want to know what other ways there are because mine for sure isn't the best way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most optimal but should do the trick:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

my_string = '''DecodingIndex[ 1]   PresentationIndex[ 2]
DecodingIndex[ 2]   PresentationIndex[ 3]
DecodingIndex[ 3]   PresentationIndex[ 1]'''

my_list = list(my_string.split("\n"))

my_dict = {}

for x in my_list:
    match = re.search("\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]$", x)
    my_dict[match.group(1)] = x

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
print(ordered_dict)
```

The part that might be slow for you is reading the file in?  This should all run very fast.  I'm starting with a string assuming you can get the file into a string.  I split the string on `\n` but you can also just read the file in so each line is an item in the list.

Then I loop it and regex match for that number you want to sort by.  Make that value the `key` in a `dict`.  Then using `collections` sort the dictionary by the key.  All done!  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks sniperd. Yes I was also writing to a file the output which I think caused the slow down!

Comment: @Baba.S Ah, OK.  Pro tip on writing out a file.  Try writing out in 'chunks'.  Append to a string like 1000 lines, and write those out.  Reset the string, append 1000 lines, etc.  Play around with that number, 10000 lines, 50000 lines, etc.  There will be a sweet spot.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) on the file (because opened text files act like a list of lines when iterated over) with a function that takes a single line and extracts the thing between the brackets as the `key=` parameter

```
import re

def extract_presentation_index(line):
    return int(re.search("\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]$", line).group(1))
    # alternatively, you don't have to use regex
    #return int(line.split('[')[2].split(']', 1)[0].strip())

with open('/path/to/your/file') as f:
    sorted_lines = sorted(f, key=extract_presentation_index)
    print(''.join(sorted_lines), end='')
```

The `end=''` is just so  you aren't adding an extra newline character (`\n`) at the end.